# Getting error when trying to add a feed to a user in GetStream

Tags: laravel, getstream-io

I'm new to GetStream API and have been trying to get it to install with Laravel. I have followed all the documentation on how to install it. However, now that I'm trying to do a simple add to a modal, I get this error.
The error im getting [image: 1]. Here is how my model looks [image: 2].
Would love some guidance. Thank you!

Comment: It's helpful to prefer posting text over screenshots depending on the kind of question. That way it's easier to copy text from the question when making an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ActivityTrait` needs to be imported before *using* it in `Want` model;
otherwise it's resolved in the current namespace.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use GetStream\StreamLaravel\Eloquent\ActivityTrait;

class Want extends Model {
  use ActivityTrait;
  #...
}
```